# Use a C++ library in swift package manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I want to use two frameworks (fat) and one C++ library in my swift package manager project. I know it's possible to convert those frameworks to XCframework that SPM can use that, but not sure that converting process works with all frameworks?

My main question is, there is a c++ library in the package as well, its description is:

> libsioclient_tls.a - this library includes the Socket.IO C++ client with TLS features.

Is it possible to add this on swift package manager, and if yes, could you please guide me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Any help on this

Comment: In theory, it's possible. A .xcframework can be created by modifying the directory structure. Swift Package Manager supports binary packages.